# May I use 洗濯日 to indicate a day for washing clothes?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I want to say a clothes washing day. Am I correctly using 洗濯日 to indicate a day for washing clothes? I seem to also remember a term sentakubiyori/youri?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such word as "先週日" in Japan.
By the way, "先週" means last week.

And sentakubiyori is ”洗濯日和”.
That means the weather is really good, and good for washing clothes (usually sunny day).

洗濯 means laundering, washing (clothes).
日和 means good weather (sunny).

Comment: I never heard other words... we usually use 洗濯日和.

but if you decide the date to washing, ex) Wednesday,

Comment: ah sorry  I accidentally pushed enter....:(

ex)every Wednesday, I wash my clothes, then you can say

my 洗濯日 is Wednesday.

Actually , there is no such word but , I can understand.

Comment: Strictly speaking, 洗濯日和 refers to the (good) weather and not the day itself.

Answer (score 1):

For "a clothes washing day / a day for washing clothes", I think you could probably say like...

> (お)洗濯の日
>   洗濯する日
>   洗濯機を回す日

as in...

> 今日は(お)洗濯の日です。
>   明日は洗濯する日じゃないんです。
>   うちは洗濯機を回す日を月・水・金と決めています。

but I think you'd probably sound more natural if you said it more simply like...

> 今日は(服を)洗濯します。 / 洗濯機を回します。
>   明日は洗濯しません。
>   うちは月・水・金に洗濯します。 / 洗濯機を回します。